# Can I derive the 1 dimensional Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution using this method?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, speed

I am aware that the 1D MB Distribution is usually derived by counting the momentum states in various directions. However, I would like to know if the following method using the 3 dimensional speed distribution should also work for the derivation.
[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/maxspe.html) states that the 3 dimensional MB Distribution in terms of speed $P(v)$ is.
$$P(v)=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_B T}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}\right) \cdot 4\pi v^2 \cdot dv$$
This would mean that the probability for a speed $v$ in 1 unit of volume in speed space would be:
$$\frac{P(v)}{4\pi v^2\cdot dv}=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_B T}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}\right)$$
If I want to compute the probability of speed $v$ but with a certain fixed value of a dimensional speed component, say $v_z$, I would predict that this would give the 1 dimensional speed distribution $v_z$ that belongs to $v$. I would deduce that this can be derived by calculating the following circular shell volume in speed space, shown in blue lines:

[image]

This circular shell volume $V$ basically contains a fixed value of $v_z$ while varying $v_y$ and $v_x$. I would therefore reason that if I formulate this volume and multiply it with the probability distribution for the speed per 1 unit of volume (previous formula), I'd get the 1 dimensional MB distribution for $v_z$. Since this circular shell volume can also be drawn at the below side of the sphere, a factor of $2$ must be added.

However, I have trouble formulating this volume in the first place. It would have a width of $v\cdot d\theta$, a thickness of $dv$ and a length of $\sin(\theta) \cdot v \cdot \int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi$ (the circumference at height $v_z$) which means that the volume is equal to:
$$V = v^2 \cdot d\theta \cdot dv \cdot \sin(\theta) \cdot \int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi$$
From [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/maxspe.html), I can see that $dv$ can be rewritten in terms of the 3 speed components and $\theta$ and $d\phi$:
$$dv = \frac{dv_xdv_ydv_z}{v^2 \cdot \sin(\theta) \cdot d\theta \cdot d\phi}$$
Substituting $dv$ with this formula would give the following formula for the volume:
$$V = \frac{dv_xdv_ydv_z}{d\phi}\cdot \int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi$$
I'm not sure how to rewrite this to be able to continue with the derivation.

Comment: @Greg.Paul Yeah, I noticed this afterwards but I don't know how to rewrite the integration otherwise.

Comment: Speed is proportional to momentum for nonrelativistic particles, but you had better stick to momentum when dealing with relativistic velocities.

Comment: @BertBarrois Am I dealing with relativistic velocities here? From what I can gather from the link I gave, it does not mention relativistic velocities. What I did is derive a concept based on that link that, at least in my mind, should give the 1D MB Distribution. But I want to verify this and know what the reason is if the concept is faulty.

Comment: If it’s relativistic, you had best use ${{d}^{D}}p\exp \left( -\beta \sqrt{{{p}^{2}}+{{m}^{2}}} \right)$ in any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation in the previous answer gives you $P(v_z)$, but my understanding is that you want $P(v_z |v)$, that is, the probability of finding $v_z$ at a fixed $v$.

You should integrate about the z-axis a ring of radius $R=v \sin\theta$ with fixed $v$ and $v_z$. The element of volume will be:

$dV=dR dv_z ds=v\sin\theta d\phi dv_z \sin\theta dv=v\sin^2\theta dv_z dv d\phi$

You can eliminate $\sin\theta$ using $v_z=v\cos\theta$ and get $\sin^2\theta= 1-(\frac{v_z}{v})^2$ and get:

$P(v,v_z)dv dv_z=2 \pi\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_B T}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} v(1-(\frac{v_z}{v})^2) \exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}\right)dv dv_z$

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I want! I have a little trouble understanding your element of volume. Shouldn't the horizontal length be $v \sin(\theta) \cdot d\phi$, the height being $dv_z$ and the thickness $dv$?

Comment: The height is $dv_z$, the thickness is in the radial direction so is dR, and the "lenght", which I think you mean the differential of circumference is $v \sin(\theta) \cdot d\phi$, you are right, I missed a factor, so the results is wrong but the idea is the same

Comment: Actually I might had make more that one algebraic error, I need to check all again. I guess it is right now.

Comment: The thickness is not $dv$ because  $dv$ points radially from the origin, it is dR because it points radially from the center of the ring

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sorry, but I don't get how you deduced that $dR=\cos(\theta)dv$. If $R =\sin(\theta)\cdot v = \sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{v_z}{\cos(\theta)}$, then I get $dR=d\theta \cdot v_z \cdot (\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}+1)$

Comment: Furthermore, rewriting my $d\theta$ in terms of your $dv$ according to $d\theta = \frac{dv}{v_z} \cdot \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ and simplifying gives me $dR = dv \cdot \big(\sin(\theta) + \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\big)$

Comment: I am so sorry, I made another mistake by doing it quickly but imprecisely.$ dR=sin \theta dv+v cos\theta d\theta$ (by the chain rule), but we keep \theta constant, so $d\theta=0$. so in this case you do not need to rewrite $d\theta$ in terms of $dv$.

Comment: No problem at all, I appreciate you helping me with this. I have one very last question and then I'm done with this. Is it actually possible to integrate our deduced $P(v,v_z)$ over $\theta$ such that it spits out the overall 1D MB Distribution $P(v_z)$? It's basically summing $P(v,v_z)$ by varying $v$ from $0$ to $\infty$ while keeping $v_z$ fixed. Since $v = \frac{v_z}{\cos(\theta)}$, one can write it in terms of varying $\theta$ instead. In that case, $\theta$ _does_ change and I would get $dR = d\theta \cdot v_z \cdot \big(\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} + 1\big)$. Right?

Comment: I am not sure you could, but let me think more about it.

Comment: Something must be wrong, I should be able to integrate v from v_z to infinity and get  p(v_z) but I dont (v cannot be less than v_Z). So, I will leave this answer to see if someone see where the mistake is.

Comment: I did dit! Rewrite $v$ as $\frac{v_z}{\cos(\theta)}$ thus $ dR = d\theta \cdot v_z \cdot \big(\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} + 1\big)$. In that case our deduced $P(v,v_z)$ for a fixed $v$ and $v_z$ is $ P(\theta, v_z)=\big(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\big)^{1.5}\cdot \exp\big(\frac{mv_z^2}{cos^2(\theta) 2k_BT}\big) \cdot \frac{\sin(\theta) 2\pi v_z^2}{\cos(\theta)} \cdot \big(\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} +1\big) \cdot dv_z \cdot d\theta$ Integrating this over $\theta$ from $0-0.5\pi$ (this angle range varies $v$ from $v_z – \infty$) gives the 1D MB Velocity Distribution for $v_z$.

Comment: It is also possible in terms of $v$ instead of $\theta$ as you tried to do. For the formulas of the ring radius $R$ and ring circumference, you have to substitute $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v_z^2}{v^2}}$. The ring volume then simply becomes $2\pi v \cdot dv_z \cdot dv$. Multiplying this with $P(v,v_z)$ and integrating over $dv$ from $v_z - \infty$ also gives the exact same $P(v_z)$.

Comment: Hello Wolphram jonny, it's been a long while but you have helped me a lot with this problem. I have posted a similar question regarding energy spheres with the MB Distribution and I'm curious if you'd like to take a look at it. Here's the link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537416/can-i-derive-the-1-dimensional-maxwell-boltzmann-energy-distribution-using-an-en

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully uderstand your reasoning, but here I show a simple derivation for $P(v_i)$. First you have
\begin{gather}
P(v_x)P(v_y)P(v_z) ~\mathrm{d}v_x\mathrm{d}v_y\mathrm{d}v_z=P(v)P(\theta,\phi) ~\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi
\end{gather}
And since the distribution is isotropic we have
\begin{gather}
P(\theta,\phi) ~\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi = \frac{\mathrm{d}\Omega}{4\pi}= \frac{\sin \theta ~ \mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi}{4\pi}
\end{gather}
Hence
\begin{align}
P(v_x)P(v_y)P(v_z) ~\mathrm{d}v_x\mathrm{d}v_y\mathrm{d}v_z&=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2m k_BT}\right) 4\pi v^2 \mathrm{d}v\times \frac{\sin \theta ~\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi}{4\pi}\\
P(v_x)P(v_y)P(v_z) ~\mathrm{d}v_x\mathrm{d}v_y\mathrm{d}v_z&=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2m k_BT}\right) v^2 \sin \theta ~\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi\\
P(v_x)P(v_y)P(v_z) ~\mathrm{d}v_x\mathrm{d}v_y\mathrm{d}v_z&=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(-\frac{m(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)}{2m k_BT}\right)~\mathrm{d}v_x\mathrm{d}v_y\mathrm{d}v_z
\end{align}
Finally you get
\begin{gather}
P(v_i)=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^\frac{1}{2} \exp\left(-\frac{mv_i^2}{2m k_BT}\right)
\end{gather}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What exact part of my reasoning don't you understand? I'm curious to know that because I want to know if my concept should give the correct 1D MB Distribution as well. Another question; does $P(\theta,\phi) d\theta d\phi$ represent an infinitesimally small surface piece on the velocity sphere?

Comment: I have improved my question, perhaps it makes it more clear. Another question, the link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/maxspe.html shows that $\int^\pi_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 v^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi = 4\pi v^2$, but how can this be integrated over $d\phi$ if the function itself does not contain $\phi$ at all?

Comment: you integrate it as a constant: $\phi v^2 sin \theta     |_0^{2\pi}$

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Thanks for the info. Could you perhaps also help me with my question in the opening post?

Comment: Your mistake is that the element of volume that you chose does not have a constant $dv_z$, but a constant $d\theta$

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Thanks, I have updated the formula in my post and improved my question. Is the deduced formula for the volume now correct? If so, I'm not sure how it should be rewritten since it also contains a $d\phi$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Your last answer made me realize my mistake, thanks! Is there a way to write $dv_z$ in terms of $d\theta$?

Comment: you dont want to have a $d\theta$. But here is it: $v_z=v\cos(\theta)$ so $dv_z=dv\cos\theta-v\sin(\theta)d\theta$