# Can I derive the 1 Dimensional Maxwell-Boltzmann Energy Distribution using an energy sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics

I was able to deduce the 1 dimensional (1D) MB Speed Distribution of, say $u_z$, by calculating the volume of two rings on a velocity sphere surface at a fixed height $v_z$ then multiply that with the 3D MB Speed Distribution formula to give the probability for a certain speed $u$ containing that fixed $u_z$ and finally integrating the whole over the angle $\theta$ which varies the 3D speed $u$ from $u_z$ to $\infty$. This will spit out the 1D MB Speed Distribution as shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499180/can-i-derive-the-1-dimensional-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution-using-this-method).

However, I am not able to do the same for the MB Distribution in terms of energy to get the 1D MB Energy Distribution for $E_z$. I know that the 3D MB Energy Distribution is:
$$P(E) = 2 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{E}{\pi}} \cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{k_BT}\bigg)^{1.5} \cdot e^{\frac{-E}{k_BT}}$$
This formula covers **one eighth** volume of surface of an energy sphere (because none of the three energy components can be negative) with thickness $dE$. This means that you would have to multiply $P(E)$ with a volume of a **quarter** ring at height $E_z$.

Knowing that $E = \frac{E_z}{\cos(\theta)}$, the quarter ring volume would thus have a length of $\frac{1}{4} \cdot 2\pi \frac{E_z}{\cos(\theta)} \cdot \sin(\theta)$, a thickness (w.r.t. $E_z$) of $d(E \cdot \sin(\theta)) = E_z \cdot \big(\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} +1 \big) \cdot d\theta$ and a height of $dE_z$.

However, multiplying this volume with $P(E)$ and integrating over $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not possible because the function is divergent.

I also noticed a problem when I consider the MB **Speed** Distribution covering one eighth of a *speed* sphere (since speed can not be negative) and trying the same calculation.

Why is this not possible?

Comment: Technically, in the non-relativistic limit one can discuss different components of kinetic energy but strictly speaking, kinetic energy is a single scalar quantity.  That is, the distribution you have shown is already a 1D function of only energy for a fixed temperature.  That is, you have a constant probability on each energy shell already.

Comment: @honeste_vivere The energy distribution I have shown is not a 1D function. The 1D MB Energy Distribution is $$P(E_x) \cdot dE_x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi E_x k_B T}} \cdot e^{-\frac{E_x}{k_BT}} \cdot dE_x$$ Energy can be split into 3 energy components but I am trying to deduce it from an energy sphere.

Comment: No, the MB distribution in terms of energy is, by definition, a one-dimensional function of just energy at a fixed temperature.  That you can decompose into subcomponents is kind of missing the point.  It's similar to the MB speed distribution.  It is also a 1D function of just speed at a fixed temperature.  Since both assume angular symmetry, you can design a 2D or 3D function from these 1D forms by just replicating the same function in all directions (kind of like azimuthal and poloidal symmetry in spherical coordinate problems).